# Exporting Insane Amount of Google Chrome Bookmarks

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks, export

I have every single bookmark that I've ever bookmarked since I was in second grade. In Google Chrome right now. And I'm trying to export them all to Diigo to see how well it would work as a bookmark manager for me (data portability is key).

Problem is, I have that insane amount of bookmarks and `chrome://bookmarks` doesn't load. It's just empty, as if it was tabulating everything. So I can't find a way to export a bookmarks.html file.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: Windows 7, Chrome 6 stable.

Comment: Just wondering, how many bookmarks?

Comment: 5, maybe 6 hundred

Comment: Wow, that's not too much at all! Specially for such the long time period saying "since second grade" may sound. But, regardless, it is an amazing number if they're all organized, alive and you use more than 50% of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way may be to get another browser to import the bookmarks from chrome and export the bookmarks from that new browser. However, all such imports require an export from the Chrome Bookmark Manager, which you say doesn't work for you.

You can also use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) to synchronizes your bookmarks using the extensions for both [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410/) and [Chrome](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1749). Xmarks also claims the ability to directly export bookmarks to HTML.

You may also be able to sync the bookmarks to your gmail account and export from there.

From [How to Use Google Docs to Transfer Chrome Bookmarks to Other Browsers](http://jkontherun.com/2009/11/06/how-to-use-google-docs-to-transfer-chrome-bookmarks-to-other-browsers/) :

1. Log in to Google Docs and look for your Google Chrome folder.
2. Select the Bookmark Bar folder, which will grab all of the contents within it.
3. Choose `More Actions`, `Export`. Leave all of the default settings and continue. Google will zip the contents and your computer should automatically download the compressed file called bookmarks.html.
4. Now that you have all of your Chrome bookmarks from the cloud, simply import the bookmarks.html file into your browser. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, Opera and most other browsers support HTML importing of bookmarks.

[image: image1]

Comment: But which browser imports Chrome bookmarks?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that one needs to pass thru a 3rd party product. Maybe Xmarks is suitable - some people swear by it as the best bookmarks manager.

Comment: Chrome's bookmark sync feature will sync them to your google docs account, though I'm not sure where you'd go from there.

Comment: @Velociraptors: I have added how to export from google docs.

Comment: Few errors, worked well enough.

Answer (score 4):

Use [MarkClouden's Google Chrome Bookmark Exporter](http://www.googlechromeboard.com/google-chrome-tips-tricks/markclouden's-google-chrome-bookmark-exporter/) - ([direct link](http://reloadedsoftware.s3.amazonaws.com/chromedump/ChromeDump.zip)) generates a single Boomarks.html fle

Comment: Do you have to access the bookmark menu in order to run the extension? That presents a use-case problem given digitxp's statement that he can't load the bookmarks screen at all, if you do.

Comment: No, it's an independent third party application which does not require Chrome, neither is it an extension.

Comment: It threw up a runtime exception, citing some missing checksum object. Then the outcome was "Bookmarks", nothing else. No dice.

Comment: You did extract all files right ? And Chrome was closed ? I tested it here, worked fine for me

Comment: @Sathya Yeah, didn't work.

Comment: @digitxp: Have you looked at the actual bookmarks file? Under Windows 7 it's located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks` and is a regular text file. As mentioned by @VxJasonxV, it's formatted as a JSON object. In the event the file is damaged, there's a backup named `Bookmarks.bak` in the same folder.

Comment: Diigo only takes in HTML bookmarks, and I don't know how to convert JSON to Bookmarks.html.

Comment: @digitxp: size is most likely not the problem (I have over 1,000 bookmarks.) Chrome uses the JSON file Bookmarks internally, and converts it to an HTML file when you export it. Since you got a checksum exception when trying to load `chrome://bookmarks` it is probably a checksum error (checksum is on line 2). Most likely your Bookmarks file is corrupted and I don't know how to generate a new checksum. Your best bet is to save Bookmarks, then rename Bookmarks.bak to Bookmarks and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your proficiency with certain programming languages, and the OS you're on, this can be very easy, or very hard.

On my computer (Mac OSX), there is a `Bookmarks` file located in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`. It is a JSON formatted file of all of my bookmarks, both those on my Bookmarks Bar as well as those in the the Bookmarks Menu, Folders included.

If you use a programming language that can read this JSON format into a native data structure, and export it back out as a Firefox formatted html bookmark collection.

There may be an extension for porting them across browsers already, it looks like Firefox will not yet important favorites from Chrome natively, only Safari when on Mac, and various other browsers from various other Operating Systems.

[edit]
I generally suggest that you use [Sathya's Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/197744/exporting-insane-amount-of-google-chrome-bookmarks/197748#197748) for simplicity's sake!

Comment: That file does not contain all of my bookmarks.  All bookmarks that are in bookmark "folders" are not there.